# I want to slide out an element with CSS then hide it with jQuery but hide seems to ignore the animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've tried a bunch of things to pause jQuery so it waits for the CSS animation but it always just immediately jumps to the .hide(). Please help!

Here's my current code:

```
$('#button').on( "click", function() {
       $( "#main-content" ).toggleClass("hide-main-content").hide();
       $( "#csp-content" ).removeClass("hide-csp-content");
    });
```

CSS: (Note I'm using a super exagerated 4.5s because I want to confirm it's finishing before .hide() kicks in.)

```
.hide-main-content, .hide-csp-content {
    right: -100vw !Important;
    -webkit-transition: all 4.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 4.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 4.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 4.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 4.5s ease-in-out;
}
#main-content, #csp-content {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  top: 0;
  right: -40vw;
  width: 60vw;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="main-content" class="hide-main-content">
 <p>MAIN</p>
</section>

<section id="csp-content" class="hide-csp-content">
 <p>CSP</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Your javascript is toggling classes called slide-main-content and slide-csp-content but the HTML and CSS reference hide-main-content and hide-csp-content. Is the intention to toggle between 2 different CSS classes to hide/show?  If so, where is the CSS for your slide-*-content classes?

Comment: clav, in trying to simplify my page to for the post I made some errors, sorry i updated the css now.

Comment: Sounds like a job for jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) where you would do the `removeClass`  in the _complete_ function that you pass to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#button').on( "click", function() {
       $( "#main-content" ).toggleClass("slide-main-content");
       setTimeout(function() {
           $("#main-content").hide();
           $( "#csp-content" ).removeClass("slide-csp-content");
       }, 4500);
    });
```

OP Edit: In the end this ended up being the solution, found it thanks to your setTimeout(function):

```
$('#button').on( "click", function() {
    $("#main-content").toggleClass("hide-main-content");
        setTimeout(function(){
           $("#main-content").hide();
        }, 500);
    $("#csp-content").toggleClass("hide-csp-content");
        setTimeout(function(){
           $("#csp-content").show();
        }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for trying but it's still instant .hide() just after a 4500 delay in which nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#main-content" ).toggleClass("slide-main-content");
$( "#main-content" ).one("transitionend", function() {
  $( "#main-content" ).hide();
}, false);
```

You need to detect the transitions end before hding it. The above adds one event listener to the element for "transitionend" then hides when it's fired. This code would replace your .hide() line.

Comment: Brandon, thanks for answering but your code doesn't run, I get a console error: 

SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','

Are you sure there's suppose to be a double function() inside .one?

Comment: @Player try that again, I had a typo!

Comment: for some reason your code is breaking my button that triggers the top click function.

 `$('a#open-case-study').on( "click", function() {`
       `$( "#main-content" ).toggleClass("slide-main-content");`
            `$( "#main-content" ).one("transitionend", function() {`
              `$( "#main-content" ).hide();`
          `  }, false);`
       
     `  $( "#csp-content" ).removeClass("hide-csp-content");`
   
  ` });`

Comment: I don't know what `one("transitionend",` is doing in your code, do I need a CSS class for transitioned?

Comment: Basically, it's adding an event listener (only once) so when your transition the code inside gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

## Perhaps, that kind of magic?

The code below will toggle visibility of 2 elements. By default `#main-content` is visible and `#csp-content` is hidden.

When the button is clicked, we toggle class `.hide-main-content` globally -- on the `body` (it could be the element itself), which results in `#main-content` sliding out and hiding (so it doesn't use any space) and at the same time `#csp-content` is un-hiding and sliding in.

If that doesn't work for you, please describe the desired **behaviour** -- what are you trying to *achieve*?

```js
$('#button').on("click", function(){
  $('body').toggleClass("hide-main-content");
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#main-content,
#csp-content {
  background: pink;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60vw;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

#main-content,
.hide-main-content #csp-content {
  right: -40vw;
  visibility: visible;
  max-height: 10000px;
}

#csp-content,
.hide-main-content #main-content {
  right: -100vw;
  visibility: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="main-content">
  <p>MAIN</p>
</section>

<section id="csp-content">
  <p>CSP</p>
</section>

<button id="button" type="button">Toggle content</button>
```

Comment: Wiktor, I have a requirement I didn't mention that my sections are only visible with position: relative; which doesn't seem to work with your setup. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Player, can you describe what exactly is the expected behaviour? From your code I assumed you want to hide `#main-content` and show `#csp-content` when the button is clicked, but perhaps I assumed wrong? I changed my code anyway, so elements truly hide and use relative positioning -- try it out.

Comment: Hey bud, thanks. In the end I acheived what I needed using  setTimeout(function), code looks like this:

`$("#main-content").toggleClass("hide-main-content");setTimeout(function(){ $("#main-content").hide();}, 500);` `$("#csp-content").toggleClass("hide-csp-content");setTimeout(function(){$("#csp-content").show();}, 500);`

It might not be pretty but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `transitionend` event listener to the element, then toggle the class.

```js
$('#button').on("click", function() {
  $("#main-content").on('transitionend', function() {
    $(this).hide();
  }).toggleClass("slide-main-content");
  $("#csp-content").removeClass("slide-csp-content");
});
```

```css
.slide-main-content {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: translateX(25%);
}
.slide-csp-content {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="main-content" class="hide-main-content">
 <p>MAIN</p>
</section>

<section id="csp-content" class="slide-csp-content hide-csp-content">
 <p>CSP</p>
</section>

<button id="button">button</button>
```